# ActionBar Compat show as action attribute missing

Tags: android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-2.2-froyo, android-actionbar-compat

Can't Use

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

in the menu XML despite I'm using the library support v7 as jar file

note: minimum SDK is 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

---

The referenced android attribute is not available. You need to use a custom namespace to explicitly reference the v7 implementation.

**My solution**:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        ...
        app:showAsAction="always"
        ...
    />

</menu>
```